# C# TargetException in PropertyInfo.SetValue() with LookUpEdit

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a LookUpEdit control and I need set property value to NullText with reflection, but I'm getting the TargetException:

```
private static void SetObjectProperty(string propiedad, string valor, object obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(LookUpEdit))
        {
            string[] vv = propiedad.Split('.');
            string prop = vv[0];
            string propType = vv[1];

            var p = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = p.PropertyType.GetProperty(propType);

            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, valor, null);
            }     
        }
    }
```

I only get the exception with LookUpEdit control.

"propiedad" is a string contains "Properties.NullText" so this is why I'm doing a split

Comment: On which line is the Exception occurring?

Comment: propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, valor, null);

Comment: What's the exact wording of the TargetException you are getting?

Comment: object does not match target type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply operations with nested properties to corresponding nested objects:

```
static void SetObjectProperty(object obj, string propertyPath, object value) {
    if(obj != null && obj.GetType() == typeof(LookUpEdit)) {
        string[] parts = propertyPath.Split('.');
        var rootInfo = typeof(LookUpEdit).GetProperty(parts[0], 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        object root = rootInfo.GetValue(obj); // obtaining a root
        var nestedInfo = rootInfo.PropertyType.GetProperty(parts[1]);
        if(nestedInfo != null) 
            nestedInfo.SetValue(root, value, null); // using root object
    }
}
```

PS. Why you're using this ugly way of modifying object properties?